# capture video frame from video file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

As the title says, I have to write some code (in VB.net) go capture a frame from a video file and save it as image. But i've no idea where to start.

Any help or idea's are welcome

So add some more info about what I what to do; I have a set of video's (I think avi files, not  sure, can't access the video's files right now). I need a picture of the video after 5 secondes of playing. And i'm programming in VB.net, that's about it

Comment: It is possible to use ffmpeg

Comment: I've never heard of ffmpeg but any possible solution is beter than none at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

See www.codeproject.com/Articles/13237/Extract-Frames-from-Video-Files. I know it is for either C++ or C#, but it shouldn't be too tough to turn it into VB code. If you prefer, I can see if I can do a code sample soon.